# rails fields_for parent id not being set on child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, fields-for

I have been working from the rails api documents for [NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and searching stackoverflow.

I have the following code in my new.html.haml view:

```
=form_for listing, :html => {:id => :listing_form, :multipart => :true} do |f|
    =f.fields_for :main_picture, (listing.main_picture || listing.build_main_picture) do |fmp|
            =fmp.hidden_field :main, :value => 1
            =fmp.file_field :image, :class => :picture_select
```

And the following code in my controller:

```
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(params[:listing])

    @listing.save ? redirect_to(:root) : render('listings/new')
  end
```

Here is my listing.rb:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :main_picture, :class_name => "Picture", :conditions => {:main => true}
  attr_accessible :main_picture_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :main_picture, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

And my picture.rb:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  validates_presence_of :listing
  attr_accessible :listing, :main
end
```

And I get the following error message when I try and submit my form:

```
main_picture.listing: can't be blank
```

I can't work out why the framework is not automatically setting the listing_id field of the main_picture (object Picture) to id value of parent Listing object.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need the `validates_presence_of :listing`? I suspect that the child record is getting created before the parent object, and so it doesn't have an ID yet.

Removing that line and adding `:dependent => :destroy` to your `has_one :main_picture` would ensure you don't end up with orphan picture records.

Alternatively, rewrite your controller:

```
p = params[:listing]
@listing = Listing.new(p)
@picture = Picture.new(p.delete(:main_picture).merge({:listing => @listing})

etc.
```

Comment: That is what I thought was happening too. The [NestedAttributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) link only says that the child model is saved "in the same transaction" as the parent. But it does not make sense to save the child first, before the parent is created and verified. I will try your suggestions and see if it changes the situation, none-the-less.

Comment: Your suggestions have stopped the error appearing and, so far as I am able to tell, everything is behaving as expected.